# RxJava Observable continue processing stream after error

Tags: java, rx-java, observable, countdownlatch

Consider this example:

```
while(currentObjectNumber < maximumObjectNumber){

        maximumObjectNumber = getMaximumObjectNumber();

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(maximumObjectNumber - currentObjectNumber);

        Observable<MyObject> observable = catchUpToMaximumObject(currentObjectNumber);

        Subscription subscription = observable.subscribe(myObject ->{
            //do some work with myObject
            currentObjectNumber += 1;
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }, throwable -> {
            System.out.println("ERROR CAUGHT");

            int x = maximumObjectNumber - currentObjectNumber;
            while(x != 0){
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                x -= 1;
            }

        });

        countDownLatch.await();
        subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Essentially I am getting an error when generating `myObject` from a HTTP response, however, I want to ignore this error and try again from the failed object. This error happens randomly and is not because of my code.

Currently, my code achieves this, however, it is quite inefficient as `maximumObjectNumber` is very large and every time there is an error the `countDownLatch` needs to go to 0. Also, `maximumObjectNumber` increases indefinitely.

I have been looking at the `retry()` method but it replays already processed `myObjects`. I am pretty sure this is the wrong way to go about it anyway but nothing on the web I have found helps improve my understanding in this situation.

The only other idea I have is to implement an `abort()` method for my `countDownLatch` so I don't have to countdown to 0 on every error.

Comment: How is the observable returned by `catchUpToMaximumObject()` defined? If it emits an error and then quits, you don't have much choice but to restart from the top. If it just emits an error specific to a particular object and might otherwise proceed, then the observable chain will be different. We need to see more code.

Comment: What does it do? What does it return?

Comment: It returns an Observable<Block> which are blocks from a blockchain. It starts from the currentObjectNumber and continues indefinitely. The error is specific to a certain block. At the moment my code just resubscribes to the observable from the last "good" block. I guess I'm asking if there is a a way to disregard the error and continue from the errored block.

Comment: Just to clarify the error is specific to a block and does not affect previous blocks, but occurs at random blocks each time I run the code. In this case block = myObject.

Comment: I believe that you will have to simply catch the error in the processing of the block, log it, and either emit nothing or a placeholder.